# Creating custom ActivityResultContract to ask for location permission

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

I would like to create a custom ActivityResultContract to request both coarse and fine location that has a custom response.

```
class LocationPermission : ActivityResultContract<Void?, LocationPermissionResult>() {
   override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Array<String>): Intent {
      val requestPermissions = arrayOf(
         Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
         Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
      )

      return Intent(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions.ACTION_REQUEST_PERMISSIONS)
         .putExtra(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions.EXTRA_PERMISSIONS, requestPermissions)
   }

   ...
}
```

Calling that from an activity:

```
private val reportLocationIntent = registerForActivityResult(LocationPermission()) { result ->
}
```

...
reportLocationIntent.launch()

However when doing so createIntent is never called.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried your code and it works on my device.

Answer (score 3):

Your code in question has compilation errors, however this approach seems to work. I don't really know what the "custom response" should be from the question directly, so I've created a class called `class LocationPermissionResult(val granted: Boolean)` based on your question. It is mostly compiled from `RequestMultiplePermissions` from ActivityResultContracts.

Tested on API 30 and API 33 emulator, the permission dialog opens and the returned result is correct as well. (Make sure the permissions are added to AndroidManifest.xml)

Here is the source code:

```kotlin
class LocationPermission : ActivityResultContract<Void?, LocationPermissionResult>() {

    private val permissions = arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    )

    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Void?): Intent {
        return Intent(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions.ACTION_REQUEST_PERMISSIONS).putExtra(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions.EXTRA_PERMISSIONS, permissions)
    }

    override fun getSynchronousResult(context: Context,
        input: Void?): SynchronousResult<LocationPermissionResult>? {
        val allGranted = permissions.all { permission ->
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                permission
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        }
        return if (allGranted) {
            SynchronousResult(LocationPermissionResult(true))
        } else null
    }

    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): LocationPermissionResult {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return LocationPermissionResult(false)
        if (intent == null) return LocationPermissionResult(false)
        val grantResults = intent.getIntArrayExtra(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANT_RESULTS)
        return LocationPermissionResult(grantResults?.all { it == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED } == true)
    }
}

class LocationPermissionResult(val granted: Boolean)
```

Answer (score 1):

this is my solution to request both coarse and fine location, i hope this will do the job

```
object Permission {
    private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION: Int = 1

    @SuppressLint("ObsoleteSdkInt")
    fun isGrantedLocationPermission(context: Context): Boolean {
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            true
        } else {
            context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        }
    }

    fun grantLocationPermission(context: Context) {
        val permissions = arrayOf(
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        )
        (context as MainActivity).requestPermissions(permissions, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION)
    }
}
```

Use it from MainActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnGetLocation)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            getLocation()
        }
    }

private fun getLocation() {
        //check if permission isnt granted:
        if (!Permission.isGrantedLocationPermission(this))
            Permission.grantLocationPermission(this)
        else {
            ...
        }
    }

//Check if user give permission or not:
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //permission granted
        } else {
            //permission denied
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    }
```

[image]

Comment: This is not what I asked for.  I would like to create a custom contract with custom results.  When trying to create a custom contract the createIntent() function is never called.

Comment: if you forgot, pls add these 2 lines in manifest

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Android 11 or above-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

I tried use your code and it worked, i changed something:

class LocationPermission : ActivityResultContract<Unit, Any>(){
...
}